# A basic question on the definition of $E[X]$

Tags: probability, statistics

My question is regarding the definition of $E[X]$ in a probability book. It starts with the definition in case of a simple random variable (a random variable which takes only finite number of values) where $E[X]$ is defined by :

$$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i P(X=x_i)$$

Now a 3-dimensional figure is drawn (I am confused about how to describe the figure in words) and it is said that from that figure it can be understood that the previous sum can be viewed as an integral over $\Omega$. With this motivation the following equation is written :

$$E[X] = \int _{\Omega}X(\omega)P(d\omega)$$

I am confused about the whole method of defining $E[X]$.

Actually, my question was why a "3 dimensional figure" is needed to describe expectation ? The finite sum I have mentioned can be thought of an uncountable sum $X(\omega)P(d\omega)$ over all $\omega$. Now, if our probability measure is Lebesgue measure, then the  uncountable sum is equivalent to $X(\omega)d\omega$ over all $\omega$ which is nothing but $\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)d\omega$ which is equal to $\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)P(d\omega)$

Comment: It's hard to answer this because you forgot to ask a question :) Are you confused about the first part or the second part. Unfortunately I don't think anybody's going to be able to explain the diagram.

Comment: One thing that might help is knowing that sums are just special cases of integrals. To make an integral, you need a measure space. When you have a finite space, you can use "the counting measure" which simply counts the number of elements in a set. The integral over the counting measure becomes the ordinary sum.

Comment: On a different note, you should try to accept answers to questions you pose. Not fair for those who spend time trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case the probabilities are assigned as discrete values.

In the second case the probability of an event (outcome) is determined by a [probability measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) $P(d\omega)$, which can be a quite general construction.  Often it amounts to ordinary integration with respect to a (nonnegative) weight called [a probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) $p(\omega)$, so that the integral can be written:

$$ E[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) p(\omega) d\omega $$

where $\omega$ represents a point in the "event space" $\Omega$.

In a first year graduate course in real analysis one is typically taught the theory of integration at a level that allows discrete and continuous measures (and probablity measures in particular) to be combined.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in elementary probability. What exactly is the definition of $E[X]$? For discrete random variables you see one thing, for continuous ones you see another. What if I am working in a problem where I have both discrete and continuous random variables at the same time? Or what if my random variables is neither discrete nor continuous? Then how do I calculate $E[X]$?

Well, the reason for this lack of definition is because the general definition requires some technical machinery from measure theory. In particular for a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb {R}$  the definition is
$$
E[X] := \int_\Omega X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)
$$
when the above Lebesgue integral with respect to the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation value is an average. For example, if I roll a pair of six sided dice a number of times and record the values, what is the average value I will get?

To see why the formula is what it is, let's look at the average value of a set of numbers. To calculate the average of a set of values, we sum the values and divide by the number of values, i.e. $$\bar x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$ Now suppose the values of $x_i$ cannot be any number but are restricted to some finite set of values as in the dice example. We can rewrite the above formula as $$\bar x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{k}n_ix_i$$ where $n_i$ is the number of times we get the value $x_i$. Note that $\sum_{i=i}^{k}n_i = n$ and $k$ is the number of values the $x_i$ can be. In our dice example, $x_i\in \{2,3,..., 12\}$ so  $k=11$.

If we move the $\frac{1}{n}$ inside the sum we get $$\bar x=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{n_i}{n}x_i$$ The fraction $\frac{n_i}{n}$ is the number of times we got $x_i$ divided by the total number of times we recorded a value, i.e. $\frac{n_i}{n}$ is the probability of getting a value of $x_i$. Therefore, we can rewrite this average as $$\bar x=\sum_{i=1}^{k}P(x_i)x_i$$ which is the expectation value.